# Does pointer notation of structures have specific style of accessing elements?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, specifications

```
struct b
{
     int c;
};

struct a
{
  struct b d[10][10];
}*e;


for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    e->d[i][0].c=11;
    //(*(*(d+i)+0)) will give you the element at that location
    e->(*(*(d+i)+0)).c=22;
    //(*(d+i)+0)-> will give us pointer to that particular element. 
    e->(*(d+i)+0)->c=33; 
}
```

within the for loop first notation is working fine but the other two notations are showing an error saying

> error: expected a field name

Two notations works fine if we use only with structure b as below

```
struct b d[10][10];
```

why is that? Is there any specification like we should not use '(' just after '->'?

Comment: Exactly as the error says - the compiler is looking for a *valid* field name, and all these `(*(d+...)` are not field names

Comment: There is no reason why you would want to use anything but the first notation anyway.

Comment: @Amit as `d[i][0]`, `(*(*(d+i)+0))` are different ways of accessing an array element and in third statements  it gives us address so used `->` after that. Obviously, it will give us the field name within `structure a` isn't it?

Comment: @Lundin I had to use the different notations of arrays to check vectorization and faced this error.

Answer (score 4):

What these lines are supposed to mean?

```
e->(*(*(d+i)+0)).c=22;
e->(*(d+i)+0)->c=33;
```

The only valid token after is `->` is a field name. In this case, `d`.

---

I think, you want something like this:

```
(*(*(e->d+i)+0)).c=22;
(*(e->d+i)+0)->c=33;
```

Comment: I checked it but its throwing `segmentation fault( core dumped)`

Comment: @Rakesh Because `e` is pointing to random junk! Assign an address of something to it.